# Why is my HP Pavilion Laptop 14-ce3xxx slowing down while plugged into the charger?

Tags: laptop, freeze, battery, hp-pavilion, lag

I’ve been using an HP Pavilion Laptop 14-ce3xxx for almost 2 years now. I can’t really tell if the thing occurs since I initially bought it but here is what happens:

Whenever I plug the charger in, the whole computer starts to likely run slower.

For example, if I am watching a youtube video, the sound will crackle from time to time, the image will freeze for a moment (while the sounds still playing), apps that were super fluent, will start to freeze, lag etc… This affects the whole system.

I’ve read some articles saying it’s something called power throttling.

I disabled it on Windows, and nothing changed. I set the battery usage to performance on Ubuntu, and nothing changed.

The thing still happens.

It’s really annoying, I have to restart the computer like 3 times, and sometimes *that* doesn’t even work and I just shut it down and get on my phone before the anger makes me throw the laptop across the room.

Any clue on what's going on and how to solve it please?